# VBA - Macro do not find Table with GetElementByTagName

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am working on automation on excel.

http://www.cresesb.cepel.br/index.php#data
In this site, when i populate Latitude and longitude and populate and click SUBMIT, many tables are displayed.

I do not know why when i try to bring the data that appears at Internet Explorer my macro just can not find.
I have checked the structure of the HTML and notice that is a little bit strange for me.

This is the data I wish to retrieve:

[image]

but what I actually get with this macro is

[image]

Can anyone help me to get this data.  I do not know why I can not find the tables.

All cell from all tables come with X,XX and I can not find any way to solve this problem.

```
`Sub ParseTable()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument 'Document object
Dim eleColtr As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for tr tags
Dim eleColtd As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for td tags
Dim eleRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Row elements
Dim eleCol As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Column elements
Dim ieURL As String 'URL

'Open InternetExplorer
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

ieURL = "http://www.cresesb.cepel.br/index.php?section=sundata"
IE.navigate ieURL

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
Set htmldoc = IE.document

Set eleColtr = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'Find all tr tags

Dim latitude As String
Dim longitude As String
Dim HTMLinputLatLong As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim botaoLat As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
latitude = "23.0150008"
longitude = "43.5519905"
Set HTMLinputLatLong = htmldoc.getElementById("latitude_dec")
HTMLinputLatLong.Value = latitude

Set HTMLinputLatLong = htmldoc.getElementById("longitude_dec")
HTMLinputLatLong.Value = longitude

'Botao

Set HTMLinputLatLong = htmldoc.getElementById("submit_btn")
HTMLinputLatLong.Click

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

i = 0
For Each eleRow In eleColtr
Set eleColtd = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(i).getElementsByTagName("td")
j = 0
For Each eleCol In eleColtd
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(i, j).Value = eleCol.innerText
j = j + 1
Next eleCol
i = i + 1
Next eleRow

End Sub
```

This code is not working.  I want to bring data but only i can get it is a X,XX;

Comment: We clearly can't answer this question without visiting the site you're trying to parse, which means that this question is off-topic because it does not meet the requirements of having all relevant content here in the post itself. See the section with the numbered list of items on [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), specifically the one discussing questions asking for debugging help.

Comment: Ken ... I am new... I will check the section and i will chenge what it needs

Comment: Post your edit this is a well explained question and certainly one of the better ones in the web-scraping tag. +

Answer (score 2):

That content is dynamically retrieved from a POST request the browser makes when you hit the submit button. So, you probably just need a long enough wait for that table to be fully loaded, you also need to work off the new content to avoid Access Denied due to attempting to access an old resource (in your select all trs line). See bottom for answer involving changes to your code.

**XHR:**

You can completely side step this waiting though as in this case you can mimic the XHR POST request the page makes and avoid a browser altogether. There are certain headers which, for VBA implementation, are required to be explicitly set.

I use clipboard to copy the main table to Excel and `querySelectorAll` to gather a nodeList of the info just above the table.

There is a helper sub to tidy up the worksheet between code runs.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, body As String, clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument                  'Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library

    TidySheet ws

    Dim latitude As String, longitude As String

    latitude = "23.0150008"
    longitude = "43.5519905"
    body = "latitude_dec=" & latitude & "&latitude=-" & latitude & "&hemi_lat=0&longitude_dec=" & longitude & "&longitude=-" & longitude & "&formato=1&lang=pt&section=sundata"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "http://www.cresesb.cepel.br/index.php", False
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3"
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"
        .send body
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim rowsInfo As Object, i As Long, r As Long

    Set rowsInfo = html.querySelectorAll("#chartdiv_0 ~ h2,#chartdiv_0 ~ div")
    clipboard.SetText html.querySelector(".tb_sundata").outerHTML
    clipboard.PutInClipboard

    With ws
        For i = 0 To rowsInfo.Length - 1
            r = r + 1
            .Cells(r, 1) = rowsInfo.item(i).innerText
            If InStr(rowsInfo.item(i).id, "chartdiv") > 0 Then Exit For
        Next
        .Range("A" & r + 2).PasteSpecial
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub TidySheet(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    Dim s As Shape

    With ws
        .Cells.ClearContents
        .Cells.ClearFormats
        For Each s In .Shapes
            If TypeName(s) = "ShapeRange" Then s.Delete
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

---

**Reading:**

1. [xhr requests](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/)
2. [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
3. [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)
4. [Document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

---

**Internet Explorer:**

This section waits for table to be present

```
Do
    DoEvents
Loop While IE.document.querySelectorAll(".tb_sundata").Length = 0
```

Then this

```
Set eleColtr = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("tb_sundata")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr") 'Find all tr tags
```

avoids attempting to access old elements as it is now being set after the button has been clicked and the page has loaded new content. Furthermore, the chained method has been altered to only target the rows of the table of interest (as shown in image you posted).

Personally, I think you should dimension and array and populate it with the results and write out the array to the sheet in one go rather than incur the expense of continually writing out each result to the sheet one by one.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ParseTable()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument          'Document object
    Dim eleColtr As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for tr tags
    Dim eleColtd As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for td tags
    Dim eleRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement            'Row elements
    Dim eleCol As MSHTML.IHTMLElement            'Column elements
    Dim ieURL As String                          'URL

    'Open InternetExplorer
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    ieURL = "http://www.cresesb.cepel.br/index.php?section=sundata"
    IE.navigate ieURL

    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Set htmldoc = IE.document

    Dim latitude As String
    Dim longitude As String
    Dim HTMLinputLatLong As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim botaoLat As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    latitude = "23.0150008"
    longitude = "43.5519905"
    Set HTMLinputLatLong = htmldoc.getElementById("latitude_dec")
    HTMLinputLatLong.Value = latitude

    Set HTMLinputLatLong = htmldoc.getElementById("longitude_dec")
    HTMLinputLatLong.Value = longitude
    Set HTMLinputLatLong = htmldoc.getElementById("submit_btn")
    HTMLinputLatLong.Click

    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop While IE.document.querySelectorAll(".tb_sundata").Length = 0

    Set eleColtr = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("tb_sundata")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr") 'Find all tr tags

    For Each eleRow In eleColtr
        Set eleColtd = eleRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
        j = 0
        For Each eleCol In eleColtd
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = eleCol.innerText
            j = j + 1
        Next eleCol
        i = i + 1
    Next eleRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for also sharing a reading list, I was about to ask for resources as I am currently dealing with dynamic websites using Selenium. Let's see what XHR has to offer.

Comment: @Lorne No worries. Any questions please ask. My profile also contains a list of links.